# Get column names when you load from an access file

Tags: sql, ms-access, dataset, ms-access-2007

I load 10 tables from an ACCESS 2007 file database.  IS their a way I can get the column names into the dataset or do I have to rename each column?  I am using Visual Studio 2008 in VB.NET.

I would like to reference the columns in the code by the name and not have to use an index

---

I just went ahead and added the following code for each of the tables:

```
Table1.column(0).name = "NAME"
Table1.column(1).name = "ADDRESS"
Table1.column(2).name = "CITY"
Table1.column(3).name = "STATE"
```

But I do this for 10 tables so it can add up fast on the lines of code. But if their is a way for me to read it from the file I would like to replace all the lines of code with one line of code.

Comment: If this is the same problem as referenced in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304666/reading-multiple-tables-from-mdb-file-into-dataset then it's VS 2008 using VB.NET and Windows Forms, all of which is information that ought to be in the question if the poster actually wants a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the dataset, if you provide a connection string locally, when you generate the xsd file it should automatically type out any tables you add to the set. As long as you're using the tableadapters built into .Net, you can change the connection string of any tableadapter you use for your local config when you deploy.

When you right-click in the blank space of the new dataset you create (in the designer), you can add->tableadapter. It'll ask you for the connetion string to the database (provide it), and then you can submit a query. Start with the a general query for the basic table you're looking for. You can then add subsequent queries as you need them to the same table or create custom tables (and names) based on joins/other queries.

EDIT: I'm assuming some version of .Net is being used here.